# reload view controller when tab pressed

Tags: iphone, reload, tabbarcontroller

I have several tabs in my tab bar controller and only one (the first one) for which I would need an automated reload each time I select its tab (and also when the app come back to the foreground).

I did not find how to do this, do I need to recreate the tab bar controller manually each time ? Do I need to add a new set of view controllers to the tab bar controller ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you need to reload? Data? Images? UITableView?

Comment: From your question, it's difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to do.  But the shouldSelectViewController and didSelectViewController methods of the UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol may be of interest to you.

Comment: In fact, when the viewController is loaded, an http request is performed. I would need this request to be performed each time I click on the tab. You'r right William, I use those both method from the TabBar protocol but I think my problem is how to use them todeallocate / reallocate the controller belonging to the first tab. Currently I use those method to check when a new tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sense to have a `updateView` functio that you can call in `viewWillAppear` on that particular view that ensures everything is up-to-date each time the view is set to appear?

Comment: The think is that viewWillAppear is only called once and not each time I click on the tab. I would need to release / init the view each time the tab is clicked in order to have this viewWillAppear method triggered. But you right, the fonction I will need to call (http request) is located in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UIViewController` is a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` it will get this callback, which is what you want, I believe:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Simply `return YES` after calling your `updateView` method.